# Enter terminal input via Python

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, terminal, operating-system

I want to switch user using the `su` command in the terminal via Python:

```
import os
os.system("su user")
```

After executing this code, the system asks for a password (obviously).

Also, of course I can't add another line like this:

```
import os
os.system("su user")
os.system("password")
```

I'd prefer an answer using Python 2.7 if it is possible.

Comment: This smells like an [XY problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem). What are you *really* trying to achieve?

Comment: You need to write to the stdin of the process. The `subprocess` module can do that. There are many example in the docs.

Comment: What I want to achieve is adding the su command to aliases WITH submitting the password, so that I won't need to insert password everytime. Python script will do because I can run the script with the terminal so I can add this command to aliases

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need `pexpect`. My lab as follow:

```
sec@sec-router:/tmp$ uname -a
Linux sec-router 3.19.0-59-generic #66~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri May 13 17:27:10 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

[image]

### Code

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import pexpect
passwd = raw_input('Password: ').strip()
child = pexpect.spawn('su root')
index = child.expect('Password:')
if index == 0:
    child.sendline(passwd)
    child.expect('$')
    child.interact()
```

Comment: Ok, I'll give it a try. Is it possible to be done using the regular os.system, or subprocess?